# Speedometer top speed

Tags: android

I have made a speedometer and want to add a top speed that I reached. I want the double to stay so I could use `SharedPreference` but would it slow down the app when running every second and potentially updating every second, also how would I make it update every second? what would be the best method? Here is all of the code relating to shared preference I have put in but I get an error saying it can't commit changes because it is in string format
The error says: 
"Android.content.sharedpreferences.editor.putstring(java.lang.String) in 'Android.content.sharedpreferences.editor' can not be applied to '(java.lang.string)'"

```
if(top_speed > mph_conversion){
    String speed =  Double.toString(mph_conversion);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor =   getSharedPreferences(top_speed, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString(speed);
    editor.commit();
}
else{
    tv3.setText(prefs.getString(speed()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use editor.apply(); instead editor.commit();

Comment: If you wanted something added to SharedPreferences you should uses (key,value) :
editor.putString("speed",speed);